# Validate form for useForm with decimal value

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, react-hooks

i am facing validation problem in useForm. For example default value is 1 decimal (6.77) when I edit it (onChange) it shows error message and then I go back to original value (6.77) it doesn't show error . If anyone has encountered this problem and solved it, please help me

Comment: are you using react-hook-form with a component library like primerReact or Ant or something else ?

Comment: i'm using it with material UI

Comment: i ran into the same kind of trouble with primerReact component. it is because since library are not exposing their ref, you need to use the controller of react-hook-form, somehting like that...it's about uncontrolled components

Comment: Yeah, i use controller of react-hook-form but not work maybe some logic is wrong, i will check it again

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.